# Using method which return a String or creating wrapper for String

Tags: java, object-oriented, comparative-review

Which approach is better and why?

First approach (inner class for wrapping):

```
public class OOP {
    private SomeService someService;

    private final class OrganizationPrimaryKeyString implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -256615521081939636L;
        private final String pkString

        public OrganizationPrimaryKeyString(final OrganizationEnum organizationEnum) {
            final PK pk = someService.getValue(organizationEnum).getPk();

            if (pk == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't be null");
            }

            pkString = pk.getLongValueAsString();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return pkString;
        }
    }

    public List<Information> getInformation(final OrganizationEnum organizationEnum) {
        final OrganizationPrimaryKeyString organization = new OrganizationPrimaryKeyString(organizationEnum);

        try {
            final SessionContext ctx = createAndSetupLocalSessionContext(organization);

            (...)

            return (...);
        } catch (final FactoryException e) {
            throw new SystemException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            closeLocalSessionContext();
        }
    }

    private SessionContext createAndSetupLocalSessionContext(final OrganizationPrimaryKeyString organization) {
        (...)
        sessionContext.setAttribute("organization", salesOrganization.toString());

        return sessionContext;
    }
}
```

Second approach (class method):

```
public class OOP {
    private SomeService someService;

    public List<Information> getInformation(final OrganizationEnum organizationEnum) {
        try {
            final SessionContext ctx = createAndSetupLocalSessionContext(organizationEnum);

            (...)

            return (...);
        } catch (final FactoryException e) {
        throw new SystemException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            closeLocalSessionContext();
        }
    }

    private SessionContext createAndSetupLocalSessionContext(final OrganizationEnum organizationEnum) {
        (...)
        sessionContext.setAttribute("organization", getPkString(organizationEnum));

        return sessionContext;
    }

    private String getPkString(final OrganizationEnum organizationEnum) {
        final PK pk = someService.getValue(organizationEnum).getPk();

        if (pk == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't be null");
        }

        return pk.getLongValueAsString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first approach is the best; it uses more design-patterns:

1. You throw an `IllegalArgumentExcaption` but `pk` is not an *argument* of the method.

   From JavaDoc:

   > Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.
2. You throw an `IllegalArgumentExcaption` because of a `null`. It should be a `NullPointerException` - it's more meaningful. `Objects.requreNonNull()` does it for you automatically. A `NullPointerException` would be automatically thrown in 2 lines later, so no need for a check except you would like to add a custom message to the `NullPointerException`. That would be a good idea.
3. The Class who has the `.getPk()`-method can have a `null` as a *PrimaryKey*; it looks like a design-flaw? Anyway, **if** this instance who has the `.getPk()`-method can have an illegal state, **then** an `IllegalStateException` should be thrown.
4. The `toString()` implementation is good.
5. `OrganizationPrimaryKeyString` is a good read-only object. Read-only objects are good for memory because you do not need to have two instances of the same organisation. But if you call `getInformation()` one million times for `ibm`, then every call to `getInformation()` returns one million equal `ibm`-objects that are not the same but require its own memory in the heap! A `HashMap` may help caching, so every call for `ibm` can return one of the same object.
6. The naming is good and meaningful. `getInformation()` should be named `getInformations()` and `OrganizationPrimaryKeyString` should only be named `OrganizationPrimaryKey`.
7. `OrganizationPrimaryKey` should be `static` because YDKJ: A subclass that is not static automatically has the wrapped-class as constructor-argument who internally is cached as a field of `OrganizationPrimaryKey`. Trust me, every Constructor of `OrganizationPrimaryKey` caches the `OOP`-Instance.

Comment: 7th require to not use the `someService`-class-variable in the `OrganizationPrimaryKey`

Comment: 1. & 2. Good point
3. This is method from 3rd part library
4. thx
5. There will be maximum 1000 invocation per day. but this is good option
6. ok

Comment: I disagree with the point you make concerning 2. Some methods are very well off with `null` as argument. I'd never expect a NPE for passing in something as an argument. Rather than that I'd prefer recieving IAE, since.. "a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument"

Comment: @Vogel612 indeed, this point is often in critic! I tend to rely on `Objects.requireNonNull()` because the JavaDoc sais `This method is designed primarily for doing parameter validation` in joyously expecting to use Lombok's `@NonNull` in the future. Btw.: Even Lombok tend to `NPE` by *default*.

Comment: @Vogel612 ... and so does Guava. Unlike Peter, they even give precedence to NPE over ISE.

Comment: @maaartinus i meant `.getPk()` shall internally throw a `ISE`. If so there is no `null` you must throw a `IAE`.

Comment: Thx for your time and help. Can you give me more detailed arguments why the first approach was better?